# Mac OS X: Where is the Application folder's icon?

Tags: macos, icons, finder

Does anyone know where the icons in the Finder sidebar are located? I'd like to use that small resolution optimized Applications icon in my app, but I can't find the original anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Whynot just do a screen grab?  (It's probably buried in a resource fork or linked into a library.)

Comment: Because I don't want the blue/gray background of Finder in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/SidebarApplicationsFolder.icns`

Comment: Avoid hard-coding paths like this. There's a good chance a new OS version will remove this image. It's happened before with others.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the icon in your source code you can get the NSImage by calling:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType: NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kToolbarApplicationsFolderIcon)]
```

You can change to kToolbar{theIcon} for getting any other icon that appears on the toolbar.